# MongoDB: Aggregation of stock tick data

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, aggregation-framework

I am using MongoDB to store my stock tick data. I have one document per stock symbol per minute:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("535fb330f6a03d59077db43c"),
"symbol" : "AAPL",
"ts_minute" : ISODate("2014-04-29T14:12:00Z"),
"ticks" : [
    {
        "mu" : 115864,
        "ae" : true,
        "t" : 2,
        "v" : 571.93
    },
    {
        "mu" : 803378,
        "ae" : true,
        "t" : 2,
        "v" : 571.91
    },
    {
        "mu" : 903378,
        "ae" : false,
        "t" : null,
        "v" : 9000
    }
}
```

where `mu` is the distance in microseconds since `ts_minute`, `t` is tick type (bid, ask, open, close, volume, etc.), and `v` is value.

To aggregate this into minutely bars of OHLC (open, high, low, close) I use the following (with PyMongo):

```
query = {'$match': {'symbol': 'AAPL'}}
projection = {
    '$project': {
        'symbol':       1,
        'year':         {'$year':   '$ts_minute'},
        'month':        {'$month':  '$ts_minute'},
        'day':          {'$dayOfMonth': '$ts_minute'},
        'hour':         {'$hour':   '$ts_minute'},
        'minute':       {'$minute': '$ts_minute'},
        'ts_minute':    1,
        'ticks':        1
    }
}
unwind = {'$unwind': '$ticks'}
sort = {'$sort': {'ts_minute': 1}}
group = {
    '$group': {
        '_id': {
            'symbol':   '$symbol',
            'year':     '$year',
            'month':    '$month',
            'day':      '$day',
            'hour':     '$hour',
            'minute':   '$minute'
        },
        'open':     {'$first':  '$ticks.v'},
        'high':     {'$max':    '$ticks.v'},
        'low':      {'$min':    '$ticks.v'},
        'close':    {'$last':   '$ticks.v'},
    }
}
bars = tick_collection.aggregate([query, projection, unwind, sort, group])
```

The problem is that I store volume ticks and price ticks in the same array. Volume ticks are identified by having `t` equal to `null`. So you see, when I group, my price ticks and volume ticks get mixed. I would like to aggregate to OHLCV, such that OHLC is based on `t` not equal to `null`, and V should be the last element of the array where `t` equals `null`.

Does it make sense? Or is it just poor schema design? ;-)

Comment: Shouldn't your group clause should also contain "ticks.t" as part of "_id"? Not sure why you do a sort before group, may be you should do that after based on the "_id" generated from the group stage, Sorting by combination of other components of "_id" and "_id.t" (from ticks.t) may give you what you want.

Comment: So what actually is the question here? Are you asking how to separate this with the schema that you have? Do you also want a discrete result for the "volume" ticks? And if so what is that?

Comment: what indexes do you have on this collection?

Comment: also it looks like your ts_minute is already a whole minute - why break it down more into subparts?  or might it actually record seconds?

Comment: I think Asya nailed it with his answer. I based my query on http://www.slideshare.net/mongodb/webinar-how-banks-use-mongodb-as-a-tick-database slide #26, which is why i sorted before group. I have indexes on `symbol` and `ts_minute`.

Comment: @AsyaKamsky: You're right. Guess I didn't fully understand the group operation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For performance, you really need to move the `$sort` to be before the unwind - it will get combined with `$match` and use an appropriate index (which would be {symbol:1,ts_minute:1} so I hope you have that index available). The project should go after `unwind` to create the price and volume fields you need for aggregation.  It seems that you should just group by ts_minute directly.  The changes to make would be:

```
query = {'$match': {'symbol': 'AAPL'}}
sort = {'$sort': {'ts_minute': 1}}
unwind = {'$unwind': '$ticks'}
projection = {
    '$project': {
        'symbol':       1,
        'ts_minute':    1,
        'volume' : { '$cond' : [
        {"$eq" : ["$ticks.t",null]},
        "$ticks.v",
        0
    ] },
    "price" : { "$cond" : [
        {"$eq" : ["$ticks.t",null] },
        null,
        "$ticks.v"
    ] }
    }
}

group = {
    '$group': {
        '_id': {
            'symbol':   '$symbol',
            'minute':   '$ts_minute'
        },
        'open':     {'$first':  '$price'},
        'high':     {'$max':    '$price'},
        'low':      {'$min':    '$price'},
        'close':    {'$last':   '$price'},
        'volume':   {'$sum':    '$volume'}
    }
}
bars = tick_collection.aggregate([query, sort, unwind, projection, group])
```